# How to ask editor for a formal acceptance letter?

Tags: publications

How can I ask editor to send me a formal acceptance letter of my paper to use it in my university?

Comment: Why would you need such a letter? If your paper has been accepted, the notification would work; if your paper hasn't been accepted, the editor can't possibly send you a formal acceptance letter.

Answer (score 4):

You send an email to the editor asking for a formal acceptance letter of your paper. Be sure to identify which paper it is about.

If desired, add a second paragraph to your email, which explains why you need such a letter. Do not hide anything necessary in the paragraph.

Be polite and to the point.